# TikZ: Fading boxes in absolute coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-fadings

I'm trying to draw a curved line, and then apply some custom fading to it by using `\pgfdeclarefading` and `\pgfsetfading` following https://tikz.dev/base-transparency#pgf.back/pgfsetfading. However, the behaviour is not at all what I expect. Using this code

```
\documentclass[class=article,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\pgfdeclarefading{fading}{\tikz \shade[top color=pgftransparent!30,bottom color=pgftransparent!70] (0,0) rectangle (1.5,1.3);}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\pgfsetfading{fading}{}
\draw [red,thick] (0,0) to ( 0.9,0.55) to [bend right = 25] (1.5,1.3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would expect that the fading box covers the line fully, applying the fading top to bottom. The result without fading is

[image]

and with fading it is

[image]

I guess coordinates of the fading box are not defined in absolute terms. Is there a way to perform the shading as such?

Comment: If I understand the manual correctly, the declared fading is centered around its origin. Thus, you need to use `\pgfsetfading{fading}{\pgftransformshift{\pgfpointxy{1.5/2}{1.3/2}}}` (or shift your path in the opposite direction: `shift={(-1.5/2, -1.3/2)}`). Does this create the picture you expected?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel That does indeed work, thank you. However, I still don't understand why the line gets cut off in the top right, outside the fading box. I would expect it not to do anything outside the box. Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: “Positions that have not been painted at all in the picture are always completely
transparent.” That's just how the fadings work, I guess.